# Operations on tumblr variables

Tags: variables, tumblr

I found some documentation on some basic operations.

For example `{PlaintextCaption}` renders `{Caption}` as plain text.

Are there any other undocumented operations available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation is documented. Here's the documentation:
[Creating a custom HTML theme: Variable Transformations](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#variable-transformations)

[image: Screenshot of Tumblr docs]

The prefixes are: Plaintext, JS, JSPlaintext, URLEncoded, RGB